# Notifications feature at top left isn't suited to text browsers/certain userstyles

Tags: feature-request, design, stack-exchange-button, stack-exchange

I use firefox with stylish and a popular global stylesheet called "Carbon nitro - dark global style" [link to the style](http://userstyles.org/styles/16903/carbon-nitro-dark-global-style). Problem is it blanks out certain images including the notifications box at the top left of stack overflow. I'm not sure if anyone would consider this a notable issue but it blocks users of text browsers from a significant piece of functionality. Thanks.

Comment: 1,805 installs, hardly popular.

Comment: applies to text browsers too, aswell as many other userstyles.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a feature-request. More like a bug. A bug in "Carbon nitro - dark global style", not StackOverflow.

Comment: elinks, lynx, links2 aswell. Fine if you don't want to support text browser I'm just saying you may aswell. It's good practice. I've voted to delete the thread since everyone seems to consider it a non-issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ link has the text "Stack Exchange" in it, it's just shifted out of the way as to not obscure the background image using a pretty common CSS technique.

The fact that the userstyle you're using removes the background image but doesn't account for cases where the image was a replacement for text (by resetting the styles used to shift it) is a fault of that userstyle, not of Stack Exchange.

Comment: That's fair enough but the functionality doesn't exist at all when using elinks as far as I can see. Of course you don't have to cater to text only users, but it'd be nice.

Comment: Stack Exchange makes a point to fully support a [specific list of browsers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208), since it's hard to cater perfectly to everyone.

Comment: Well fair enough then. I'll consider the issue closed.